# doxygen generated make.bat stops with errors. How to prevent such stops?

Tags: doxygen, pdflatex, miktex

How can I prevent stops on errors and automate it always to proceed without interaction?

I called that make.bat batch script after my doxygen (1.8.16 on Win10) generated all that stuff in a latex directory. My installed latex is from basic-miktex-2.9.7100-x64.exe.

But that make.bat stops several times with the following errors, and I had always to press the R key and Enter key to go on. But in the end I get that result PDF file called refman.pdf which looks great at first glance.

The error situation is:

```
...snip...
Ap-pli-ka-ti-on be-fra-gen, wie das z.[]B. in []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 569--569
[]\T1/phv/b/n/10 Last

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 569--569
\T1/phv/b/n/10 Changed[]

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 569

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 572--574


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 577

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [19]
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
<to be read again>
                   }
<argument> ... {stringliteral}{"\(\backslash \)1"}
                                                   : \textcolor {stringliter...

\DoxyCodeLine ...\hangpara {\DoxyCodeWidth }{1}{#1
                                                  }\par
l.603 ...(\backslash\)2"}, 1, DP\_SD\_NO\_FLAGS);}

?
```

---

EDIT: I found out I could hack the make.bat the way like this diff:

```
- set LATEX_CMD=pdflatex
+ set LATEX_CMD=pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode
```

but what is the option in my doxygen configuration to let doxygen do this on its generating of the make.bat script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set the `LATEX_CMD_NAME` and this also accepts the options, so you can set:
`LATEX_CMD_NAME="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode"`

(note it is strange that you get errors, this indicates that something goes wrong / is unexpected in the generated LaTeX code and this should be fixed. It is by coincidence that you get a nice pdf file but I think that when searching for "Applikation befragen, wie das" in the pdf you will see some anomalies)

Comment: Great, thanx! The text processed by doxygen is actually "Applikation befragen, wie das z.B. in @ref MyClass::process_control_index geschieht". It seems to me Doxygen cannot render the link because my configuration misses a path to the source file of that C++ class. But I think pdflatex should actually not stumble on it but just ignore the missing link. Do you also have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Without source code / example it is hard / impossible to tell.